# How to save unlimited lengthy string in derby using Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have the following pojo with the annotation. But it doesn;t persist the largeString to database.

```
@Lob
@Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.TextType")
private String largeString;
```

Comment: What do you mean be doesn't persist? Do you get an exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had long space characters in the lob. After I trim my String it began to work fine.